# "Cannot Login Unless Logout Another User First" on Asus Router

Tags: router

I have an RT-AC68U Asus Router. The admin password stopped working. After many unsuccessful tries, I did a factory reset.

After the reset, the router gives the following error:

[image: error screenshot]

The resource, [Asus RT-AC66: Cannot Login Unless Logout Another User First](https://fatmin.com/2017/03/06/asus-rt-ac66-cannot-login-unless-logout-another-user-first/#:%7E:text=This%20error%20is%20usually%20caused,or%20if%20your%20browser%20crashed), suggests using `ssh` if possible:

> This error is usually caused by improperly closing router’s WebUI. This can occur if you are logged in and lose connectivity, or if your browser crashed.
>
> Fortunately, the fix is simple… Assuming you have SSH enabled.
>
> First, SSH into your router and run the two commands shown below.
>
> ```
> admin@RT-AC66U:/tmp/home/root# nvram unset login_ip
> admin@RT-AC66U:/tmp/home/root# nvram commit
> ```

However, after a factory reset, the ssh is *not* enabled.

The other suggestion is:

> If you do not have SSH or telnet enabled, you can just power cycle your router.

I have already power-cycled the router and that did not resolve the issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to power-cycle the router once or twice more to make sure the session token is wiped.  After one, (or a few), reboots you should regain access to the web interface where you can enable ssh or telnet wo you have a workaround for the next time.

Comment: Yea just trying another time worked. The scientific method.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when you try to login on 2nd device while you are logged in on 1st device. so logout from the 1st device then you will be able to login

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS Safari, if you don't see an open session to your router in your browser tabs, you may have a session open in one of your `Tab Groups`!!

(I could ssh in but the stated method didn't work. I finally found and closed the session in a tab group I had been using earlier in the day)